# Add columns with predefined values to a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to add new columns to a dataframe, populated with predefined values stored in another dataframe. What is the best way to proceed?

Nice to have: is it possible to make the code dynamic in case new variables appear in d2?

### data for reproducible code

```
d1 <- head(iris)                      # dataframe 1 ----------

var <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
val <- c(5, 7, 1)
d2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(var, val))  # dataframe 2 ----------
```

### Expected output

First dataframe

[image]

Second dataframe

[image]

Desired output

[image]

Best regards

Comment: What about `d1$var1 <- d2[1, 2]; d1$var2 <- d2[2, 2]; d1$var3 <- d2[3, 2]`? :)

Comment: Fyi, `as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))` is not so good, as `cbind` constructs a matrix, coercing `x` and `y` to have the same class (character/string here). Better to do `data.frame(x,y)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be (this will work for any number of `var`s)

```
d1[as.character(d2$var)] <- rep(d2$val, each = nrow(d1))
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species var1 var2 var3
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    5    7    1
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    5    7    1
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    5    7    1
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    5    7    1
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    5    7    1
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa    5    7    1
```

Comment: Ha. Happened before I could even modify my post.

Comment: Thank you both! This is what I need (I was fighting unsuccessfully with the mutate function from dplyr..)

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(d1)[, as.character(d2$var) := as.list(d2$val)]
```

`as.character()` is required because of the way you've created `d2`, which resulted in `var` being `factor`.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
d1 <- head(iris)                      # dataframe 1 ----------

var <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
val <- c(5, 7, 1)
d2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(var, val)) 

for (i in 1:nrow(d2)){
  d1[[as.character(d2$var[i])]] <- rep(d2$val[i],nrow(d1))
}
```

I imagine there is some way of doing it without a for loop. I expect the big guns will arrive shortly and reduce this to one line :).

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few approaches that transpose `d2`:

```
d3 <- d2["val"]; rownames(d3) <- d2[,"var"]
cbind(d1,t(d3))

d4 <- do.call(data.frame,setNames(as.list(d2$val),d2$var))
cbind(d1,d4)

dlist5 <- setNames(as.list(d2$val),d2$var)
do.call(data.frame,c(d1,dlist5))
```

In all of these cases, `val` remains a string, which is not great. Starting from `val` and `var`...

```
cbind(d1,t(data.frame(val,row.names=var)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use tidyr package as well.
It works well for me, though.

```
library("tidyr")

# transform to new columns
df <- spread(d2, var, val, convert = T)
df[1,] <- df[!is.na(df)]
df <- df[1, ]

# combine columns
result <- d1 %>% cbind(df)
```